# Jmeter could not extract response value

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Using Jmeter n my Json response couldn't extract the below `"_MESSAGE_"` response value as well need to capture first five value in our variable like (10000) alone

```
"{\"_STATUS_\":\"SUCCESS\",\"_MESSAGE_\":\"10000,1111111111\"}"
```

Note : This is invalid json and dev team not supporting to build the right json.

it's high priority task - anyone have a solution for this issue. please share your input.

I am looking for the solution to extract the `"_MESSAGE_"` and need to capture first five value in our variable like (10000) alone

Comment: is it only invalid JSON because it includes the `"` at beginning an end? Can you just strip those off and then parse the json inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boundary Extractor and use "MESSAGE":" as left boundary
and , as right boundary

Comment: Right boundary should be , Not " (As you need to capture first five value in our variable like (10000) alone

Answer (score 0):

Given response is not a valid JSON you have 2 options:

1. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the relevant regular expression would be something like:

   ```
   "MESSAGE":"(\d{5})
   ```

   [image]

   See [Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) chapter of JMeter user manual for explanation of what do these `()`, `\` `d` and `{5}` mean
2. [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) where you can just provide "left" and "right" boundaries and JMeter will extract everything in-between

   [image]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

Comment: response message has some special character like "_MESSAGE_\ ":\"10000.111111\"}

Comment: I tried with \\"_MESSAGE_\\":\\"(.*?)\\" in regular exp. if capturing all message response value. like "111111,10000000"} . But need to capture only 111111 alone

Comment: Tried - \\"_MESSAGE_\\":\\"(\d{5})\\" - Match count: 0